# Adding empty list to list of lists

Tags: scala

I have list of lists like this:

```
List(List(1, 2, 3), List(1, 2), List(1))
```

I want to get

```
List(List(1, 2, 3), List(1, 2), List(1), List())
```

or

```
List(List(), List(1, 2, 3), List(1, 2), List(1))
```

Standart concatenation didn't work, so what should I do?

Comment: Hi if the answer below worked could you accept it. Solved questions help SO users focus on older unsolved questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me.

```
scala> val ls = List(List(1, 2, 3), List(1, 2), List(1))
ls: List[List[Int]] = List(List(1, 2, 3), List(1, 2), List(1))
scala> val newLs = List()::ls
newLs: List[List[Int]] = List(List(), List(1, 2, 3), List(1, 2), List(1))
```

Comment: @qwwdfsad the append operator is `:+`

Answer (score 1):

```
val l = List(List(1, 2, 3), List(1, 2), List(1))
l: List[List[Int]] = List(List(1, 2, 3), List(1, 2), List(1))

List()+:l
res0: List[List[Int]] = List(List(), List(1, 2, 3), List(1, 2), List(1))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ls::List()
```

is wrong syntax

```
List()::ls
```

works but you have to assign it to a new List. You can't modify the original ls because it is immutable.